# Correct order of certificates in a certificate chain (gradle build cache node)

Tags: java, ssl, gradle, keystore, pkcs#12

I'm trying to setup a gradle build cache node using the JAR distribution available [here](https://docs.gradle.com/build-cache-node/#jar). Currently I'm facing issues regarding the SSL configuration as the cache node fails to start with this exception:

```
2019-11-13 09:24:16,671 INFO c.g.b.n.BuildCacheNodeMain {} Using OpenSSL-RefCount SSL support
2019-11-13 09:24:16,671 INFO c.g.b.n.BuildCacheNodeMain {} OCSP Stapling enabled
2019-11-13 09:24:16,904 ERROR c.g.b.n.c {} Application failed to start -  com.gradle.buildcache.node.e.b: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failed to set certificate
and key
        at com.gradle.buildcache.node.BuildCacheNodeMain.b(SourceFile:382)
        at com.gradle.buildcache.node.BuildCacheNodeMain.a(SourceFile:364)
        at com.gradle.ratpack.h.d.b(SourceFile:142)
        at com.gradle.ratpack.h.d.a(SourceFile:109)
        at ratpack.server.internal.RatpackServerDefinition.build(RatpackServerDefinition.java:43)
        at ratpack.server.internal.DefaultRatpackServer.lambda$buildUserDefinition$4(DefaultRatpackServer.java:207)
        at ratpack.impose.Impositions.impose(Impositions.java:117)
        at ratpack.server.internal.DefaultRatpackServer.buildUserDefinition(DefaultRatpackServer.java:205)
        at ratpack.server.internal.DefaultRatpackServer.start(DefaultRatpackServer.java:115)
        at com.gradle.buildcache.node.BuildCacheNodeMain.<init>(SourceFile:173)
        at com.gradle.buildcache.node.BuildCacheNodeMain.main(SourceFile:205)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failed to set certificate and key
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:130)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:75)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:59)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:474)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:457)
        at com.gradle.buildcache.node.BuildCacheNodeMain.b(SourceFile:380)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.setKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:704)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:601)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:111)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1174)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.buildKeyStore(SslContext.java:1092)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:115)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.setKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:651)
        ... 20 more
```

I basically placed my key and the cert file (including all intermediates) in the `<data-dir>/conf` folder as described in [gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.com/build-cache-node/#using_your_own_certificate).

The certificate was issues by Sectigo and the chain has 2 intermediate certificates:

```
$ openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile certificate_chain.cer | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout
subject=/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
issuer=/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root

subject=/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
issuer=/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root

subject=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
issuer=/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority

subject=/CN=<FQDN>
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
```

Using OpenSSL I can verify the certificate chain without issues:

```
$ openssl verify certificate_chain.cer
<FQDN>: OK
```

As I could not figure out what was going on I tried to debug the import of the key and certificate chain to the key store and ended up in [`sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.validateChain(Certificate[])`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/8e859259bc46c65c5310801899b48e3df0a92989/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs12/PKCS12KeyStore.java#L1520) and this loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < certChain.length-1; i++) {
    X500Principal issuerDN = ((X509Certificate)certChain[i]).getIssuerX500Principal();
    X500Principal subjectDN = ((X509Certificate)certChain[i+1]).getSubjectX500Principal();
    if (!(issuerDN.equals(subjectDN)))
        return false;
}
```

It basically checks that the issuer of a certificate in the chain matches the subject of the next certificate in the chain. As you can see in the `certificate_chain.pem` file above it was just the other way around. The first cert in the file is the Root CA and the last one is the actual server certificate. So I reversed to order of the certificates in the chain file and - behold - the key and chain could be imported.

If I now try to verify the reversed chain with OpenSSL it fails:

```
$ openssl verify certificate_chain_reversed.cer
certificate_chain_reversed.cer: CN = <FQDN>
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Now I'm wondering what the correct order of intermediate certificates in a chain file should be. Should the file start with the server certificate and and with the Root CA's certificate (as required by `PKCS12KeyStore`) or should it be the other way around (Root CA first and server certificate last) which is working in OpenSSL?

Even more confusing: Using `JKS` as key store type instead of `PKCS12`, import of the certificate and chain works in Java without issues as well. However the key store type doesn't seem to be configurable for the gradle cache node...